# Add to chart not working says error in Add.php file as shown in the picture

Tags: magento2

[image]

This is where the error is on $params =$this->get request()->getParams();

Comment: Seem the file is  corrupted.`return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');` seems error.

Comment: what error shows while trying add to cart?

Comment: [2020-02-17 15:58:49] main.CRITICAL: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '$params' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /home/371821.cloudwaysapps.com/uxbdgrudkh/public_html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php:92

Comment: Is your Magento version supports PHP version which you have in a server?

Comment: I don't know how do I check that?